# Xamarin.UITest REPL connection refused

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I'm beginning UI automated testing with Xamarin.UITest in Xamarin Studio.  I'm using the basic `CreditCardValidator` project given by Xamarin. My tests work as expected, but when I try to add the line `app.Repl();` to query the UI and enter the `tree` command (or any other for that matter), I keep getting the error:

```
App has been initialized to the 'app' variable.
Exit REPL with ctrl-c or see help for more commands.

>>> tree                                                                        
Execution failed with exception: System.Net.WebException: Error: 
ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) <0x3acc998 + 0x0017b> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) <0x3aca8f8 + 0x004b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) <0x3acdbe8 + 0x00187> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2 endFunction, System.Action`1 endAction,     System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) <0x1944280 + 0x00069> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x18aa010 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a7830 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a7790 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a7740 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x18a8040 + 0x00024> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () <0x3abbe30 + 0x00df3> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient.Request (System.String method, System.String endpoint, ExceptionPolicy exceptionPolicy, Nullable`1 timeOut) <0x3aadc68 + 0x0040f> in <filename unknown>:0 
at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient.Get (System.String endpoint, ExceptionPolicy exceptionPolicy, Nullable`1 timeOut) <0x3aadc18 + 0x0003b> in <filename unknown>:0 
at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidGestures.Dump () <0x3aadb18 + 0x00053> in <filename unknown>:0 
at Xamarin.UITest.Utils.TreePrintHelper.PrintTree (ITreePrinter treePrinter) <0x3aada28 + 0x0002a> in <filename unknown>:0 
at Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppPrintHelper.Tree (Nullable`1 console) <0x3aad950 + 0x0008b> in <filename unknown>:0 
at <InteractiveExpressionClass>.Host (System.Object& $retval) <0x3aad830 + 0x00047> in <filename unknown>:0 
at Mono.CSharp.Evaluator.Evaluate (System.String input, System.Object& result, System.Boolean& result_set) <0x2ede1b0 + 0x0008f> in <filename unknown>:0 
at Xamarin.UITest.Repl.Evaluation.MonoCSharpReplEngine.Evaluate (System.String line) <0x2ede0a0 + 0x00057> in <filename unknown>:0 
at Xamarin.UITest.Repl.Repl.ReplFacade.RunCode (System.String code) <0x2edde88 + 0x00063> in <filename unknown>:0 
at Xamarin.UITest.Repl.PromptHandler.PrintTree () <0x3aa4e50 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0 
at Xamarin.UITest.Repl.PromptHandler.HandleInput (ConsoleKeyInfo key) <0x3a38520 + 0x001da> in <filename unknown>:0 
at Xamarin.UITest.Repl.Program.Main (System.String[] args) <0x71def8 + 0x003ef> in <filename unknown>:0 
Press any key to exit.
```

I have added the `INTERNET` permission in the app and the tests, themselves, run fine.  The code for the tests is:

```
public class RecorderTest
{
    public IApp app;
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        app = ConfigureApp.Android.Debug().ApkFile(<path/to/apk/>).StartApp();
    }

    [Test]
    public void CreditCardNumberTooShortError()
    {
        //app.Repl();
        app.Tap(x => x.Id("creditCardNumberText"));
        app.Screenshot("Tapped on view with class: AppCompatEditText");
        app.EnterText(x => x.Id("creditCardNumberText"), "1234");
        app.Tap(x => x.Id("validateButton"));
        app.Screenshot("Tapped on view with class: AppCompatButton");

        AppResult[] result = app.Query(c => c.Class("AppCompatTextView").Text("Credit card number is too short."));
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Any(), "The error message is not being displayed");
}

    [Test]
    public void CreditCardNumberTooLongError()
    {
        app.Repl();
        app.EnterText(x => x.Marked("creditCardNumberText"), new String('9', 17));
        app.Screenshot("Entered Credit card number");
        app.Tap(x => x.Id("validateButton"));
        app.Screenshot("Tapped on view with class: AppCompatButton");

        AppResult[] result = app.Query(c => c.Id("errorMessagesText").Text("Credit card number is too long."));
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Any(), "The error message is not being displayed");
    }

}
```

I've used the **Calabash** Framework by Xamarin as well and I can use the `console` command and query the app just fine.  Not sure whey this isn't working with Xamarin.UITest.

I'm running Java 1.7, NUnit 2.6.3 and Xamarin Studio 6.0.1 (build 9)

Comment: What are you trying to run the test on ? Is it an emulator or a physical device ?

Comment: I've tried this on both an emulator and physical device with no luck.

Comment: I'm struggling with these kind of cryptic Repl/UI test deployment errors on a daily basis, yet I've never seen this one in particular. My first guess would have been to include the INTERNET permission, but you already have it. The only potential solutions that come to mind are: 
1) Having the latest dev version of Xamarin.UITest 
2) Letting the IDE do the deployment instead of referencing the APK path directly 
3) Switching between Debug/Release mode (and disabling shared runtime if in debug) 
4) Disabling any proxy, VPN connection or other service (i.e. Fiddler) that could interfere.

Comment: I'll try those suggestions and let you know.  Thanks

Comment: Tried all except letting the IDE do the deployment. Not sure how to do that.  Any suggestions?

Comment: There's obvously a web call being made, one that does not succeed. You could try to find out more information about the nature of that call by sniffing/logging. Hopefully you'll get a guilty port number that is no configured properly or another clear indication of the target of this call and why it fails.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am getting this in Android not in iOS. However when calling backdoor methods I get this error

Comment: Unfortunately I have not resolved this